# Вывод значений из mongodb node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Не получается получить информацию из `db.findOne()`, все находится, но не могу вытянуть значения из запроса во внешние объекты.

```
var test;

collection.findOne({name : name}, function (err, item){
    console.log(item.name, item.value);
    test = item.value;
});
```

Comment: А что у вас находится в db? Коллекцию выбирали или db  - это соединение с MongoDB?

Comment: Это коллекция. Неправильно сюда вставил. Сейчас подправлю.

Comment: Если не сложно добавьте еще содержимое коллекции find().limit(3), чтобы можно было ориентироваться в структуре коллекции.

Comment: Скажу честно, сейчас сложно. Пол дня пытаюсь разобраться, голова устала. Вот прямо иp коллекции {"name":"vodka","value":565,"date":{"$wrap":"$date","v":1463399211376,"h":"2016-05-16T11:46:51.376Z"},"_id":{"$wrap":"$oid","v":2},"__v":0}
{"k":"0000000078","o":"0000000139","v":"001"}

Comment: В консоль внутри функции все выводится правильно.

Comment: Просто что-то не видно ключа с названием name.

Comment: Переменная name в корректно заполнена?

Comment: Да, там name. Попровил тут. Я получаю правильный данные тут  console.log(item.name, item.value); и все...

Comment: Сейчас столкнулся с тем, что findOne дает promise... И на этом я запнулся.

Comment: @Bedisom, имеет в виду в первом параметре findOne() в условии {name : name} все корректно? В коллекции есть ключ name, а JS-переменная name заполнена?